# Pass value from non-native cordova plugin back to ionic 4

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am unable pass value from non-native cordova plugin back to ionic. I am using ionic 4. I am also unable to using router when I'm inisde the event listener of cordova plugin.

```js
var browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("XXXX, '_blank', 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function (e) {
    if (e.url.indexOf('XX') != -1) {
        browser.hide();
        this.router.navigate([Constants.DASHBOARD]);
    }
});
```

Hit error uncaught below:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Comment: Can you post your full code. `this.router` does not exist. So your `this` does not point where you think it is pointing. You are having scoping issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`browser.addEventListener('loadstop', function (e) {`

to

`browser.addEventListener('loadstop', e => {`

Arrow functions maintain the scope of their parent. Using function defines its own scope. So with an arrow function `this` will point to the parent which has a router. With a function, `this` points to the function which does not have a router.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this
>   from its enclosing scope.